# SAML 2.0 implementation in .NET, which library to use

Tags: .net, authentication, wif, saml-2.0, component-space

We are about to implement support for SAML 2.0 in our company and we have been going through a long list of libraries ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services#Libraries_and_toolkits_to_develop_SAML_actors_and_SAML-enabled_services)) that would allow us to implement such identification for our systems more practically (us being the `Service Provider`).

I recently found out that .NET 4.5 comes with native support for SAML 2.0 through WIF (Windows Identity Foundation). However, having native support by .NET, should we consider using a popular third-party libraries such as [ComponentSpace](http://www.componentspace.com/) (or anything better perhaps)? Are there any benefits in regards to ease of use, broader settings, flexibility or documentation?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831961/how-does-the-asp-net-identity-compare-with-windows-identity-foundation

Comment: I haven't personally tried this but it looks credible: itfoxtec.com/Saml2

Comment: https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml (disclaimer: I'm one on the contributors)

Answer (score 4):

WIF doesn't support SAML (the protocol). It supports WS-Fed with SAML **tokens**. If you really want to go down the SAML (protocol) you need to use some other library like ComponentOne's.

**TL;DR:** 
WIF, at least theoretically, can do SAML-P too if you extend it. Microsoft wrote this extensions as a "[preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx)" in 2011, but has not updated yet since. You can do it too using the WIF extension model. Most people I know have better things to do though :-).

In general, I would recommend going with a lighter weight, syntactically simpler protocol like OpenID Connect. Plenty of easy to use, simpler to debug, troubleshoot libraries out there.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) and the links in it.

Having used ComponentSpace, it works and has a good selection of samples and the cost is pretty reasonable.

Obviously, commercial = support.

Not sure about your use case but you could possibly install ADFS and then go:

ASP.NET --> WS-Fed (WIF) --> ADFS --> SAML --> IP.

Comment: Yes, that works too. But it looks like a lot of plumbing :-)

Comment: Possibly, but in my experience with a number of customers it's a whole lot easier than  trying to get a SAML stack working if you've never done it before.

Comment: Yes. Completely agree. Or use Auth0 and you get the best of the two worlds :-). Can you ping me on email? I couldn't find a way to connect with you. http://stackoverflow.com/users/349524/eugenio-pace

Comment: To flesh out @Eugenio's comment, I wrote this up: http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/04/saml-net-application-talking-to-saml-idp.html